# Vim replacing in inverse direction

Tags: vim, replace

How can I replace in Vim from current line in inverse direction (upward) (for searching I'm using `?textToFind`, for replacing from current position `:,$s/a/b`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use backwards range with `:s` command.

If you want to do replacement from line 1 to your current line, you can do `:,1s/foo/bar/g` vim will ask you if you are sure to apply command on a backwards range, press `y`

You can also do something like `:,-3s/foo/bar/` to do replacement from current line (`n`) till line `n-3`

Answer (score 1):

The range used for `s//` (and other Ex commands) can be made of:

- line numbers, `1,23`
- relative lines, `-5,+17`
- line shortcuts, `.,$`
- marks, `'a,'g`
- searches, `?foo?,/bar/`
- or any combination of the above items, `?foo?,'g`, `23,$`, `+5,/bar/`, `.,/baz/+6`…

A range extending from the first instance of `foo` before the cursor to the last line could look like that:

```
?foo?,$
```

A range extending from the first instance of `foo` before the cursor to the current line could look like that:

```
?foo?,.
```

and even be shortened to:

```
?foo?,
```

Comment: It's not what I need.

For example if we have the file with 3 lines each with letter 'a' and cursor is on the third line, than I want to replace 'a' from the 3rd line, then 'a' from the 2nd and then 'a' from the 1st.

Comment: You should ask clear questions if you want meaningful answers. The `s//` command *always* goes downward so either you do `:-2,.s/a/b` or you use another method: a recorded macro or maybe `cgN` and `.`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to visit the lines from the end to the beginning. Vim will issue a `Backwards range given, OK to swap?` query, and turn around the range if confirmed. The only way is by manually specifying the individual lines in reverse order:

```
:.s/a/b | .-1s/a/b | .-2s/a/b | ...
```

Of course, you can write a custom command for that.

If you also require reverse replacement *inside* a line (all of that only makes sense with the `c`onfirm flag, doesn't it?), you're out of luck with `:substitute`.